# Subir ficheros desde java a Onedrive

Tags: java, jsp

Buenos días, estoy realizando una aplicación para gestionar correos y me gustaría saber si desde java hay manera de subir los adjuntos a una cuenta de Onedrive.
Seguramente se podrá imagino, si es así que librería debería de tener para poder hacerlo o donde podría ver algún ejemplo para ver más o menos su funcionamiento.
Gracias.

Comment: Existe una API de One Drive para subir archivos, [aquí tienes una información inicial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659726.aspx#Upload_a_file) que puedes revisar y a partir de ella hacer un intento de código. Ver también [este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth) para obtener el token. Y [aquí un ejemplo de código](http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare/tutorial/uploadfileonedrive.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Buenas de nuevo, estoy probando subir archivos a mi onedrive. En el ejemplo que tengo en el Service es :https://independentsoft-my.sharepoint.com/personal/info_independentsoft_onmicrosoft_com, según entiendo es de Business, en mi caso que es personal como se la url?